# Como tratar esse código array com php?

Tags: php, array, atributos

Tenho uma dúvida, de como tratar esse array:

```
["*original"]=>


array(13) {
["id"]=>
int(1)
["user_id"]=>
int(3)
["reference"]=>
string(36) "c8d2076672c9631e8c048589f3a9a26f3961"
["status"]=>
string(8) "Pendente"
["paymentMethod"]=>
string(2) "ph"
["date"]=>
string(10) "2018-08-30"
["paymentLink"]=>
string(195) ""
["created_at"]=>
string(19) "2018-08-30 17:41:39"
["updated_at"]=>
string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
["pacote"]=>
int(1)
["tipo"]=>
string(20) "Ativação de pacote"
["valor"]=>
float(0)
["transaction_id"]=>
NULL
```

}

Precio recuperar o array transaction_id, porém o atributo ["*original"] não deixa, por causa desse asteristico.

Alguém pra resolver comigo?

Answer (score 0):

Teoricamente seria isto:

```
$recuperado = $var["*original"]["transaction_id"];

var_dump($recuperado);
```

Mas como teu array mostra NULL:

```
["transaction_id"]=>
NULL
```

Então o valor é nulo.

O asterisco não atrapalha em nada, veja o teste: https://ideone.com/cPnbtZ, provavelmente o problema é no valor `null` ou algo que você fez errado na sintaxe do seu código pessoal

Comment: assim não vai não

Comment: undefined *original

Comment: @AlissonMaciel se não vai é porque você esta com uma variavel diferente, ou algo assim, no link que enviei mostrei, funciona, o problema é algo que você fez, provavelmente o array deve ter mais dimensões.